# appium autotest password input of Android APP in emulator but password input field is missed in xml file

Tags: android, passwords, appium, emulation

I am using appium-desktop to record password(8 characters) input function of An android APP on Android emulator(UI is [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGv6K.png)) to figure out how to write python script to autotest this function. I couldn't figure out which element(s) to send key(s) in order to input password(I attach the xml file which is after I input 2 characters of password(totally 8 characters) in the end for your reference).
I tried selecting the most likely element(ex. com.test.android.test:id/cb_1, cb_2, ...) to send key the following error in the inspect function of appium-desktop:

Call to 'sendKeys' failed
[element.sendKeys("w")] Error response status: 12, InvalidElementState - An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element). Selenium error: Cannot set the element to 'w'. Did you interact with the correct element?

I did some investigation and found out after I input one character of password, the corresponding id/cb_1 became 'checked=true' from 'checked=false'(the attached xml file is catpured after I input 2 characters, so cb_1 and cb_2's 'checked=true' and others(cb_n)'s 'checked=false'), nothing else changed in xml file.So my question is how I should write python code of inputing 8 characters password for appium to automate the test.

Could Someone provide some hint or advice for me to move forward? Thanks for your help! Your advice is highly apprecied!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="3" width="900" height="1600">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][900,1600]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][900,1600]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][900,1600]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/root_view" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][900,1600]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][900,604]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][900,118]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/btn_close_area" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][110,118]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/btn_left" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[30,61][74,105]" displayed="true" />
              </android.widget.FrameLayout>
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
            <android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,118][900,192]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.TextView" text="your account will be locked if retrying password errors over 5 times" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/hint" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,118][900,192]" displayed="true" />
            </android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/pwd_input_fl" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,324][900,604]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,324][900,367]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.TextView" text="pls input your password" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/dialog_verify_password_title" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[306,324][594,367]" displayed="true" />
              </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
              <android.widget.RelativeLayout index="1" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,427][900,511]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,427][876,511]" displayed="true">
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,427][130,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_1" checkable="true" checked="true" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[55,447][99,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[130,427][236,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_2" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[161,447][205,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="2" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[236,427][342,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_3" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[267,447][311,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="3" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[342,427][448,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_4" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[373,447][417,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="4" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[448,427][555,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_5" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[479,447][523,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="5" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[555,427][662,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_6" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[586,447][630,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="6" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[662,427][769,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_7" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[693,447][737,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="7" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[769,427][876,511]" displayed="true">
                    <android.widget.CheckBox index="0" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.CheckBox" text="" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/cb_8" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[800,447][844,491]" displayed="true" />
                  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
                </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
              <android.widget.TextView index="2" package="com.test.android.test" class="android.widget.TextView" text="forgot password?" resource-id="com.test.android.test:id/btn_forget_password" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,571][900,604]" displayed="true" />
            </android.widget.LinearLayout>
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
        </android.widget.RelativeLayout>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

Comment: There is no XML

Comment: xml file has been added in code format(the previous xml was put in text and has been cut short ),  Thanks for the help! @adrenalineWest

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, the android developer of this app used checkBox for password placeholder instead of input. This is wrong and no one does this in real production.
And UiAutomator won't let you sendKeys to a checkbox.

Anyway, if this is a sample apk for a test, try to `driver.set_text("password")` to the parent element of the checkbox (LinearLayout or FrameLayout). If fails call the app developer!

Comment: Thanks! It fails!!! And the develope who wrote this quit,:(